# get attribute value of a newly prepended element

Tags: jquery, attributes, prepend

I have the following html:

```
<ul><li rel="3">text<li><li rel="2">text<li><li rel="1">text<li></ul>
```

then I prepend a new li element:

```
$("ul li:first").prepend('<li rel="4">text</li>');
```

Problem:

when I get the value of the attribute(rel) of the newly added element like this:

```
alert( $('ul li:first').attr('rel') );
```

..I keep getting "3" instead of 4...but I need the new one!

Hope somebody can help me!

TIA

Comment: You should close your <li> elements with </li>, not another <li>.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong in the call to `prepend`. Do this instead:

```
$('ul').prepend('<li rel="4">text</li>');
```

Beforehand, you were prepending an `<li>` to the first `<li>`, not to the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to prepend the new li element, it will work fine.

```
$("ul").prepend('<li rel="4">text</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are prepending to the child element (the li) .
you'd need to do a
 `$("ul").prepend('<li rel="4">text</li>');`
Also, check those closing `<li>`, should be `</li>`

Answer (score 0):

prepend inserts element as first child in your object, so when you use prepend
use it

```
$('ul').prepend('<li rel="4">text</li>');
```